# job change during probation

Tags: new-job, job-change

I want to change my job as a java engineer during my probation period.Reason being salaries are not paid on time and there is no communication to the employees,...management is not bothered about employees at all. It has been 3 months and my probation is 6 months.I am trying for a new job with in my probation period.As I don't want to lie on other reasons, does the other company really cares about it or will it give any negative impact for my CV if I tell them this reason. This is my second job change after 9 years and there is no other case like that..can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean 'go out and get a job with a different company',  by all means go for a new job.

A probation period is a probation on **both** sides. You and the company you are working for are not a good match, nor would they be a good match for anyone who considers being paid on time important.

I would be careful about saying the management didn't listen to you, as the people you interview with will have no idea if that means 'I asked when I would get my paycheck and they just shrugged' or if it means 'I demanded something outrageous and they refused.' It's best to leave out anything that could be interpreted as a poor reflection on you. Fortunately, 'paychecks were sometimes (frequently, always) late' is generally considered a more than sufficient reason to leave a company.